# std::string optimal way to truncate utf-8 at safe place

Tags: c++, string, utf-8

I have a valid utf-8 encoded string in a std::string. I have limit in bytes. I would like to truncate the string and add ... at `MAX_SIZE - 3 - x` - where `x` is that value that will prevent a utf-8 character to be cut.

Is there function that could determine `x` based on MAX_SIZE without the need to start from the beginning of the string?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have a location in a string, and you want to go backwards to find the start of a UTF-8 character (and therefore a valid place to cut), this is fairly easily done.

You start from the last byte in the sequence. If the top two bits of the last byte are `10`, then it is part of a UTF-8 sequence, so keep backing up until the top two bits are *not* `10` (or until you reach the start).

The way UTF-8 works is that a byte can be one of three things, based on the upper bits of the byte. If the topmost bit is `0`, then the byte is an ASCII character, and the next 7 bits are the Unicode Codepoint value itself. If the topmost bit is `10`, then the 6 bits that follow are extra bits for a multi-byte sequence. But the *beginning* of a multibyte sequence is coded with `11` in the top 2 bits.

So if the top bits of a byte are not `10`, then it's either an ASCII character or the start of a multibyte sequence. Either way, it's a valid place to cut.

Note however that, while this algorithm will break the string at codepoint boundaries, it ignores Unicode grapheme clusters. This means that combining characters can be culled, away from the base characters that they combine with; accents can be lost from characters, for example. Doing proper grapheme cluster analysis would require having access to the Unicode table that says whether a codepoint is a combining character.

But it will at least be a valid Unicode UTF-8 string. So that's better than most people do ;)

---

The code would look something like this (in C++14):

```
auto FindCutPosition(const std::string &str, size_t max_size)
{
  assert(str.size() >= max_size, "Make sure stupidity hasn't happened.");
  assert(str.size() > 3, "Make sure stupidity hasn't happened.");
  max_size -= 3;
  for(size_t pos = max_size; pos > 0; --pos)
  {
    unsigned char byte = static_cast<unsigned char>(str[pos]); //Perfectly valid
    if(byte & 0xC0 != 0x80)
      return pos;
  }

  unsigned char byte = static_cast<unsigned char>(str[0]); //Perfectly valid
  if(byte & 0xC0 != 0x80)
    return 0;

  //If your first byte isn't even a valid UTF-8 starting point, then something terrible has happened.
  throw bad_utf8_encoded_text(...);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the byte patterns of UTF-8 encoding are such, that it's trivially possible to determine the boundary where the next character begins.

Comment: I know the data - I just do not want to iterate from the begging to find which is the truncated /if any/ character

Comment: The question is can I determine where the character I am in begins.

Comment: Find the end of the previous character, according to the other answer, then incrementing the position by 1.

Comment: @gsf: Your question should make that more clear. Also, I've added an answer to that.

Comment: This will allow a string to be truncated at a codepoint boundary, but it may change the characters in the string rather than just cutting them off. E.g. it might result in "résumé" being turned into "résume".

Comment: @bames53: Good point, though that is what the OP asked for. I added that to the answer though.

Comment: the for loop is not correct, size_t is unsigned and it is always >= 0;

for(size_t pos = max_size; pos-- > 0;) will do

Comment: @gsf: Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @bames53: In all fairness, cutting characters can turn any word into nonsense. "haai" to "haa" is just as gramatically wrong, just in Dutch instead of French. (Can't have suffix -aa)

Comment: _But the beginning of a multibyte sequence is coded with 11 in the top bits (and the number of bytes in the sequence is determined by how many 1s follow those two before the first 0)._

Is this correct? To me it sounds like it's conflicting with the description in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), which explains that the number of bytes in the code point is determined by the *total* number of 1's at the beginning of the first byte, *not* the number of 1's that *follow the first two*.